# An exception when trying to remove an event handler from ThreadPreprocessMessage

Tags: c#, exception, interop

Trying to add my event handler to `ComponentDispatcher.ThreadPreprocessMessage` event like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Cc();
        }
    }

    public class Cc
    {
        public Cc()
        {
            ComponentDispatcher.ThreadPreprocessMessage += Method;
        }

        ~Cc()
        {
            ComponentDispatcher.ThreadPreprocessMessage -= Method;
        }

        private void Method(ref MSG msg, ref bool handled)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And when I run it, I get this exception in the destructor:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: LocalDataStoreSlot storage has been freed.

What causes it and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.componentdispatcher.aspx) state. The register and unregister calls are stored in a thread local data structure. You just did try to unregister in a finalizer which is run on the finalizer thread (== Different Thread). This will not work since you must unregister on the same thread where you did register.

Comment: So should I remove unregister call from the destructor and make call to Dispose method (which will unregister the action) explicitly?

Comment: Yes but as I said. You must call dispose on the same thread where you did register. The "destructor" is called finalizer in .NET and does not the same as in C++. It is called for objects which are no longer connected to any static object reference chain. For these objects their finalizer (if they have one) is called on a thread that does nothing else as calling the finalizer on dead objects.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Didn't know that finalizer has its own thread.